# AWS S3 Bucket Policy "Access Denied" while editing in web interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a new S3 bucket through the web console, and I'm just trying to update the bucket policy, but i get an unhelpful error message:
"Error: Access denied"

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have rights to update the bucket policy? You might have sufficient rights for Listing, Creating, Deleting, etc, but miss the ones related to Bucket access management.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to disable "Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies (Recommended)" in public access settings before updating the bucket policy

Answer (score 0):

(For me) It works after I disabled *Block new public bucket policies (Recommended)* since it was a new public policy.